# Why is dynamic allocation used for Linked lists?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, structure

```
Struct node { char ch; node *link;};

node * temp = new node;
node *temp1;
```

My question is why we use the first way for declaring a dynamic structure and not the second one. I tried to use the second one, coupled with a class to mimick a stack but the display() function made it into an infinite loop, whereas using the former corrected it. Why?

Comment: For starters, I assume you realize c/c++ are both case-sensitive? `node` is not the same as `Node`. Either way is fine `Node *temp = new Node` or `Node *temp1`- they are both equivalent in fact. The first example not only declares the variable, but also allocates memory for it. The rest of your question relates to code you've not shown. No comment can be made on unseen code!

Comment: the second one you mean `Node temp` without a star ?

Comment: @enhzflep They are not equivalent. One instantiates a `node` object, the other one doesn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza - as I said already "The first example not only declares the variable, but also allocates memory for it". Declaration != instantiation. (or does it??) You've simply made the same point that I did, albeit more succinctly, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not entirely clear, but this

```
Node *temp1;
```

simply creates a pointer that doesn't point to a `Node` object. In fact, it points to a location that you could consider random. You cannot de-reference this pointer, you have to make it point to a `Node` first.

This, on the other hand

```
Node * temp = new Node;
```

dynamically allocates a `Node` on the RHS, returning a pointer to `Node`, the value of which is used to initialize `temp`. So `temp` points to a valid `Node` object. Bear in mind that at some point you will have to call `delete` on everything allocated with `new`. In modern C++, you would avoid this manual memory management and delegate it to a type such as a smart pointer.

**Note** The above assumes the type in question is called `Node`, not `node`.

Comment: I get your point, but what I don't understand is , even without using the dynamic allocation of node, the pointer seemed to work at first. How Is that?

Comment: @HarjyotSingh What do you mean by "work"? Your code doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

A linked list CAN be constructed without using `new`, but in most cases, that is not a very practical solution. The reason we use linked lists (and trees, and other "linked" data structures) is to have some way to store arbitrary number of elements in structure where it is easy to add/remove elements in the middle. If that wasn't the case, we could just as well use an array or a vector.

We could make a short linked list by doing this:

```
Node a, b, c;
Node *head = &a;  // Head is the pointer to the first element. 
a.link = &b;
b.link = &c;
c.link = NULL; 
// Clearly we want to set ch in each node as well, but I'm ignoring it for shortness.
```

But this gets very messy if we don't know how many links we need.

So, we use the heap to allocate elements because we don't know beforehand how many they are.

The linked list uses pointers to "next" (or "previous") nodes in the list - that way, we can easily insert an element in the middle of the list. Or remove an element from the middle.

In a vector of 1000 elements, to remove the first element means moving 999 elements "up one step". To remove the first element in a linked list requires essentially one change: Move the head of the list to the next element.

Removing the 500th element of a vector requires moving 499 elements to "up one step". Removing the 500th element of a linked list requires that the link from the 499th is chanted to point at the 501st element. This will take one operation. (Of course, we also need to FIND the right element to remove, but unless the elements in the vector are sorted in some way that helps searching, that's essentially the same effort).